# How remove accessibility alert "Low Contrast" in Google Play Console?

Tags: android, accessibility, game-development, google-play-console

I'm developing a game for Android using Supernova Engine (https://github.com/supernovaengine/supernova) but I'm having trouble getting rid of the "Low contrast" alert by Google Play Console.

Element path: `"android:id/content/FrameLayout[1]/m[1]"`

Recomendation: "The item's text contrast ratio is 1.21. This ratio is based on an estimated foreground color of #000000 and an estimated background color of #1A1A1A. Consider increasing this item's text contrast ratio to 3.00 or greater."

[image]

Supernova Engine uses this Activity class for Android:
https://github.com/supernovaengine/supernova/blob/master/workspaces/androidstudio/app/src/main/java/org/supernovaengine/supernova/MainActivity.java

But I cannot find where is this element: `"FrameLayout[1]/m[1]"`.

Comment: You would have to raise a bug on [SuperNova's github](https://github.com/supernovaengine/supernova/issues) for this. They need to fix it.

Comment: I'm the developer of Supernova Engine too. I made this game to validate the engine.

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR: I suspect if you set the text and hint color of this component to a color contrasting to black (e.g. white) you will probably get rid of this error.

```
getText().insert(this.getSelectionStart(), " ");
```

Having white space in here might also be throwing the Play Store check off

Some other things to try:

Loading this screen up with an un-proguarded debug version and using Google's [Accessibility Scanner](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.accessibility.auditor&hl=en_GB&gl=US)? This should help you diagnose these types of issues in the future

Alternatively you can do an `adb shell uiautomator dump` and try and find the offending child in the XML there. This requires more sifting though, you'd need to know what you were looking for.

I tried checking out the code and running, but got too many errors. From what I can see in [MainActivity](https://github.com/supernovaengine/supernova/blob/master/workspaces/androidstudio/app/src/main/java/org/supernovaengine/supernova/MainActivity.java), you are doing the following to create the view:

```java
layout = new FrameLayout(this);
layout.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
setContentView(layout);

setFullScreen();

edittext = new TextInput(this);

layout.addView(edittext);
layout.addView(glSurfaceView);
```

Where `TextInput` is some sort of Hybrid view - inflated from code without styles being set. Your problem is probably there somewhere.

Comment: Thank you for these tips, I will try those on next release. This TextInput is hidden, it is necessary to manage keyboard and text input to engine. I have already removed accessibility checks in it with setImportantForAccessibility(View.IMPORTANT_FOR_ACCESSIBILITY_NO_HIDE_DESCENDANTS)

Comment: Have you tried to run the code using Mac? I fixed the errors that were happening with Mac.

Comment: Yes it was a mac! I hope some of the suggestions help!